# android:configChanges="orientation" with surfaceChanged

Tags: android, android-orientation, surfaceholder, android-configchanges

In one activity implementing `SurfaceHolder.Callback`, I include the line `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to stop the activity from being redrawn when, among other things, the screen is rotated.  However, `surfaceChanged()` still gets called when the screen is rotated.  Is this intentional, and how can I get the behaviour I want, which is to completely ignore rotations?

Comment: By completely ignore rotations, do you mean you want the orientation fixed to either portait or landscape?

Comment: Yes, whatever the default orientation of the device is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's no better solution than a manual hack: set a boolean variable once surfaceChanged is called for the first time (i.e. when the surface is created), and return at the beginning of surfaceChanged if this variable is set.